# Is there an HAProxy virtual machine I can download?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, haproxy

Is there an HAProxy virtual machine (any OS) with HAProxy installed but not configured (or configured and I'll just reconfigure)?

Comment: HAProxy is extremely simple to install on Debian...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't (to my knowledge anyway) however it's trivial to install on most distributions.  Create a small VM with your distribution of choice and then install the HAProxy package.  On Debian based distros it's as easy as `apt-get install haproxy`.  For CentOS/RHEL, you'll need to add the EPEL repo, and then `yum install haproxy`

Comment: You should be able to find lots of barebones straight CentOS appliances, just get one of these and install haproxy.

Comment: I agree with this. haproxy is seriously only one single binary. Its total footprint is not much more. Even if there is no package for your distribution of choice, simply create a small VM and download the binary from their website.

Comment: https://www.haproxy.com/products/main-features-of-aloha-load-balancers/aloha-load-balancer-virtual-appliance/